# Login through API (using passport) in multi tenant (hyn package) laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, multi-tenant, laravel-passport

This is the Error:

> RuntimeException: Personal access client not found. Please create one. in file /var/www/html/pharmacy/vendor/laravel/passport/src/ClientRepository.php on line 94

This is my login function:

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'remember_me' => 'boolean'
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        if (!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
        $user = $request->user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;
        if ($request->remember_me)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
        $token->save();
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                $tokenResult->token->expires_at
            )->toDateTimeString(),
            'name' => Auth::user()->name,
            'email' => Auth::user()->email,
        ]);
    }
```

This is my route file `api.php`:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'User\ParticipantAuth@login');


    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'User\ParticipantAuth@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'User\ParticipantAuth@user');
    });
});
```

I just want to login  through passport package API in multi tenant

I copied all the migration created by passport package from `database/migration` and put it into `database/migration/tenant` folder where other migrations are saved.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, as great as this site is, it is not a debug service  but a Question and Answer site. Read more about it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). I recommend reading [What types of question should I avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 11):

Before your application can issue personal access tokens, you will need to create a personal access client:

You need to create a [personal access token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#personal-access-tokens)

```
php artisan passport:client --personal
```

Comment: what about php artisan passport:install --force?

Comment: RuntimeException: Personal access client not found. Please create one. in file /var/www/html/pharmacy/vendor/laravel/passport/src/ClientRepository.php on line 94

Comment: Did you try php artisan passport:install --force?

Answer (score 1):

Happens if you never ran the `php artisan passport:install` and often each time you happen to drop the tables.

Simple run `php artisan passport:install` without necessarily using the `--force` flag